# HTML5 video control jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video on a site, but didn't like the look of the controls just sitting over the poster image, so i added this jQuery to add controls on hover,

```
$('#MSvideo').hover(function toggleControls() {
    if (this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
    this.removeAttribute("controls")
    }
    else {
    this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
    }
});
```

In theory this works, it does add the controls on hover, but if you leave the mouse on the video just sat there the controls go on, then off, then on, then off, about once a second repeatedly.

It does the same thing in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/konbsda8/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I checked the jsFiddle, but I do not seem to be getting the results you are. What browser are you using?

Comment: Using Firefox 33.1, I was worried it might have been a browser thing, if it is would it be a fixable browser issue?

Comment: Definitely a browser issue, as there is no issue in Chrome.. If you inspect the video on Firefox, you can see that as the mouse moves over the video, the property 'controls="controls"' is added and removed. I believe that is causing the flickering issue.

Comment: Yes sorry i should have mentioned that, the issue is that the attribute is being added and remove repeatedly, not that its just flickering. Is there a way of writing my jQuery so it sets the attribute on mouse in and removes it on mouse out, and do away with the IF statement?

Comment: Have you tried mouseenter and mouseleave? I have doubts that will work considering Firefox is acting as if the mouse is not hovering the video when clearly it is, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured this out, the controls attribute needs to be blank, so the line

```
  this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
```

should instead be

```
  this.setAttribute("controls", "")
```

And this seemed to solve the blinking effect.